# Why do I get a linker error?

Tags: c++

Why do I get a linker error?

```
/*
test.cpp
© Andrey Bushman, 18 Jun 2013
*/
//--------------------------------------------
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//--------------------------------------------
namespace Bushman{
//--------------------------------------------
    class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass();
    };
//--------------------------------------------
    MyClass::MyClass(){
        void func(); // declaration
        func(); // call
    }
//--------------------------------------------
    void func(){ // definition
        cout << "Ping..." << endl;
    }
}
//============================================
int main()
try{
    namespace B = Bushman;
    B::MyClass a;
}
catch(exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
catch(...){
    cerr << "Unknown exception." << endl;
    return 2;
}
```

Result (by MS Visual Studio 2012):

```
C:\bs\13>cl test.cpp /EHsc
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler
Version 17.00.51106.1 for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All
rights reserved.

test.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.51106.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe test.obj test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
symbol "void __cdecl func(void)" ( ?func@@YAXXZ) referenced in
function "public: __cdecl Bushman::MyClass::MyClass( void)"
(??0MyClass@Bushman@@QEAA@XZ) test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1
unresolved externals

C:\bs\13>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `namespace B = Bushman;` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Hmm.. I just copied and compiled the code and it ran fine in Cygwin g++ 3.4.4  Debugger says it exited normally.

Comment: @olevegard I assigned a short prefix instead of a full name.

Comment: Those comments with all the dashes actually impede clarity, rather than improving it.  I would recommend removing them, and list using extra line breaks if you want to have extra separation between sections.  You also need to indent properly in the main method.

Comment: @Elazar No, for the 'main' function is allowed to write try/catch like me.

Comment: @Elazar: What's wrong about it ? It is guaranteed to work by the standard.

Comment: Could it be that you link with an older version of the generated object file somehow ? Apparently this code builds and links fine.

Comment: @AJMansfield No, I think it is more clear. I formated my code according to recommendations by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: @Bush I assume Elazar was pointing out the missing `{` after `int main()`

Comment: @ereOn No, I removed all files before. I use MS Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @Bush The reason they are a problem is because the horizontal lines distract from the actual code.  At my first glance, the lines tricked me into thinking that you had the function and constructor inside the class's curly braces, for example.  Separating sections is what curly braces and indentation are for.

Comment: Compiled and ran fine in g++ 4.5.1
Looks like a VS-only thing.

Comment: @olevegard I've answered to him earlier. It is not misprint, and not error. It is an allowed syntax for the 'main' function.

Comment: @Bush it is not a common idiom, and hence not clear. Regardless of Stroustrup's taste. Same goes for the missing braces.

Comment: @AJMansfield Horizontal lines allow to distinguish separate fragments of a code (definitions) quickly visually.

Comment: @Bush try putting your first { on a newline after the block you are defining. This will give you some white space to act as a buffer without having to have the dotted lines. Of course, this is a personal preference. So if what you do works for you then it works. But I agree with AJMansfield when he says that the dotted lines distract from the actual code.

Comment: @Elazar I actually agree with leaving out the enclosing braces around the main method body.  It emphasizes the idea that the exception handling is something for the entire method, not something it's doing for just a few steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your compiler is erroneously introducing the name into the global namespace, rather than the innermost enclosing namespace (`Bushman`) as specified by C++11 3.5/7:

> When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found to refer to some other declaration, then that entity is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace.

The code compiles as expected on GCC: http://ideone.com/PR4KVC

You should be able to work around the bug by declaring the function in the correct namespace before (or instead of) declaring it in the constructor's block scope. However, I don't have access to your compiler to test that.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace Bushman{
    MyClass::MyClass(){
        void func(); // declaration
        func(); // call
    }
    //--------------------------------------------
    void func(){ // definition
        cout << "Ping..." << endl;
    }
}
```

You declare `func()` inside the `MyClass` constructor. This *should* be the same as the `func()` you defined in the `Bushman` namespace; but it appears that your compiler gets that wrong. Generally declaring a function inside another function or inside a constructor is considered bad practice. Instead you should declare functions directly in the scope where you intend them to be. In this case, you need a forward declaration of `func()` inside the `Bushman` namespace:

```
namespace Bushman{
    void func(); // declaration

    MyClass::MyClass(){
        func(); // call
    }

    //--------------------------------------------
    void func(){ // definition
        cout << "Ping..." << endl;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can split your code into separate .h and .cpp files. In fact, this is ideal. I suggest putting `func()` in `func.cpp` with a declaration in `func.h`. Similarly put the `MyClass` declaration in `myclass.h` and the `MyClass` definitions in `myclass.cpp`. Now `myclass.cpp` should `#include "func.h".

Using header files this way gives you fine-tuned control over forward declarations and ensures that everything is defined when it is needed.

Comment: I've tried to use full names: 
`void Bushman::func(); // declaration
Bushman::func(); // call`
but it is ain't working too.

Comment: @Bush Did you try my suggestion here? In short, your forward declaration is declaring a *different* function than the one you later define.

Comment: @Bush you clearly missed the point of this answer.  Please read the second half of the answer.

Comment: @AJMansfield Yes, I know the second variant is working. I know it before than I've asked a my question. But I want to understand why not work my first variant.

Comment: The declaration and the definition *should* refer to the same function, according to C++11 3.5/7 (which includes a very similar example). It looks like the compiler is wrong, not the code; although it's good advice in general to put function declarations in headers as you suggest.

Comment: @Code-Guru global scope? But I use my own namespace, not global... Yes my h and cpp files are separated in the life.

Comment: Sorry, but it's even more wrong after the edit. You define another function with the same name *in the innermost encolsing namespace*, not *with global scope*. (At least, that's what a confoming compiler should do; apparently, it's not what this one does).

Comment: @Mike Seymour I have not edited my code in this topic. It was edited by other men, without  my solution.

Comment: @Mike Okay, I give up on explaining *why* the error occurs and decided to focus on emphasizing best practice.

Comment: @Bush Mike is referring to *my* code since he posted a comment to my answer not your question.

Comment: @Bush Please read the complete answer now. I believe I have refined it enough to explain the "correct" way to write your code. While you *can* declare a function inside another function (or constructor), it is not typically done that way.

Comment: @Code-Guru Yes, I understand, what practice is good and what is a bad. My question was about other. I wrote syntactically the correct code which theoretically doesn't contradict rules C ++ and shall be compiled successfully. But it didn't occur and to me it is interesting.

Comment: @Bush It sounds like your compiler doesn't comply with the standard in this regard...is that surprising?

Comment: @Code-Guru it is not my compiler. It is the MS Visual Studio 2012. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a function

```
  void func()
```

Which is shadowing the method

```
void MyClass::func()
```

So your call is calling the undefined function, rather than the method.

Comment: But there is no `MyClass::func()`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Exactly.  It never gets defined.

Comment: My class has not a `void MyClass::func()`. Therefore ambiguities can't arise.

Comment: @AJMansfield: Nor declared, so there is nothing to shadow. There is only one `func`, in the namespace `Bushman`, and both the declaration and definition *should* refer to that. Apparently, this compiler incorrectly interprets the declaration as declaring something different.

Comment: I get it now: `MyClass::MyClass(){void func(); //declaration` doesn't actually declare any sort of function `func`.

Comment: @AJMansfield: Yes it does. It *should* declare a function in the surrounding namespace, which *should* match the later definition. But this compiler seems to get it wrong.

Comment: @AJMansfield Yes, that *does* declare a function. Apparently in VS2012, the function isn't declared in the enclosing namespace and so doesn't match up with the *defined* function there.